# How to link an Intranet website to my Internet accessible website

Tags: http, dns

I've configured a dinamic DNS with my router and linked my external IP to no-ip.com, so I have a link to my intranet from everywhere. Now I have done a simple port forwarding from the port 80 to 8080 to my laptop, which is hosting a http-server with node.

Everything works fine but now I want to create a link to my router configuration, that I can access with the IP 192.168.1.1 from my laptop, directly from my website, hosted on my laptop. Can I do that in some way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing a small code on a web server, which makes a call to the router config url and shows the output.